# OneSignal how to send Push Notification to specific users in ionic2

Tags: android, push-notification, ionic2, onesignal

I am using OneSignal to send notification and I was able to send a notification successfully but now I want to send them to a specific user
or users I know I can create a segment to identify these users but
let say I have a segment for company A and another for company B 
how can I add a new user to that segment.

so, in short, this is how the idea in my mind works in my DB I have users that belong to company A and another to company B they open the app and subscribe now how I give them a key to identify them do I send the key from my application or I store it in my DB?

Comment: You will need to store playerId (Device id) in users tables and then send notification to specific device. https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#section-send-to-specific-devices

Comment: but the playerId is just numbered how will I know which company the user belongs to?

Answer (score 1):

The ability to set data tags is incredibly powerful. You can store data attributes on each user. Tags are available on all OneSignal accounts and are a very popular feature among our customers. Users are tagged with attributes such as types of messages they want to receive, content categories, cart abandonment info, subscription status and user-preferences.

Read more on data tags [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/data-tags).

We have more details in our [blog post](https://onesignal.com/blog/data-integration-and-tagging-using-onesignal/) on data integration with OneSignal